# how to update date column with some default timestamp in liquibase

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

How to update date column with default value(2010-01-01 00:00:00) in liquibase.
I am know to get the current date. Can you please suggest me to update column with some default value.

```
 <property name="now" value="SYSDATE" dbms="postgresql">

 <changeSet>
    <update>
      <column name="date_created" valueDate="${now}"/>
    </update>
 </changeSet>
```

Comment: I tried with this <property name="now" value="TIMESTAMP '2010-01-01'" dbms="postgresql"> Its is working fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The attribute `valueDate` supports three formats:

1. YYYY-MM-DD
2. hh:mm:ss
3. YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss

In your case this works:

```
<column name="date_created" valueDate="2010-01-01" />
```

Comment: I tried with this <property name="now" value="TIMESTAMP '2010-01-01'" dbms="postgresql"> Its is working fine. I should get time-stamp as well. with yours i only get date not date and time. anyways thank you

Comment: If you need date and time then use 3): 2010-01-01T23:42:00.